# Does everything in a promise chain have to be a promise?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, sequelize.js, chaining

This is a simplified example of my actual code, but I'm trying to make sure that this is valid. My question is regarding the second item in the promise chain below.

```
// vars photo and image are declared outside of the promise chain

// ...
.then(() => Photo.create()) // this is a promise
.then(p => photo = p) // this is just assigning a variable, no promise
.then(() => image.resize({ height: 240 }).toBuffer()) // this is another promise
// ...
```

It works, but is this a good way to handle this? The reason I'm organizing it like this is I basically have an intermediate step where I need to do some assignments and calculations etc, and just organizationally I want to keep it separate from my other `.then()` sections that are actual promises.

Comment: No. You *can* do it the way you're doing, but it doesn't make much sense when there's nothing asynchronous going on. Call a function instead, and separate that function into separate functions if you want.

Comment: Yes or no depending what you mean by "everything in a promise chain".

Answer (score 1):

> Does everything in a promise chain have to be a promise?

Well, you have to start with a promise at the head of the chain because otherwise you don't have a thenable to call `.then()` on.

But, other than that, no.  Items in a `.then()` chain do not have to use promises or return promises.  You can run any Javascript.  What matters for the next link in the chain is the return value from the `.then()` handler.

If the return value from your `.then()` handler is a plain value (no promise involved), then that value will be passed to the next `.then()` handler.

If the return value from your `.then()` handler is a promise, then the resolved value of that promise will be passed to the next `.then()` handler and the promise chain will not advance until that promise is fulfilled.

---

But, if there is nothing asynchronous in the chained `.then()` handler, then you could just combine it with the previous or next link of the chain and eliminate that `.then()` handler which simplifies things.

For example, this chain:

```
then(() => Photo.create()) // this is a promise
.then(p => photo = p) // this is just assigning a variable, no promise
.then(() => image.resize({ height: 240 }).toBuffer()) // this is another promise
// ...
```

can be reduced to this:

```
then(() => Photo.create()) // this is a promise
.then(p => {photo = p; return image.resize({ height: 240 }).toBuffer()}) // this is another promise
// ...
```

---

FYI, your specific example here doesn't even really need to be  chain because the `image.resize()` isn't using the result of `Photo.create()` so unless this is just an artifact of you making up some code to post, those two operations could be run in parallel and don't have to be chained.  Promise chains are for situations where operations must be sequenced, often the output of one step is part of the input to the next step.

Comment: @Glenn - Did this answer your question?